# Call a dll function from InstallAware or InstallShield

Tags: c#, .net, installshield, installaware

Does any body know how can i call a dll function from InstallShield or InstallAware.

Comment: What does the documentation of those products tell you? What problems did you encounter when you tried to follow the documented instructions?

Comment: The documentation tell me that i can call a dll function, but there is no any code sample to show me show to do it.

Comment: @Ghyath I don't believe that. I suggest you look harder in the documentation.

Comment: @Ghyath Also, it's often the case that you don't actually need to call a custom DLL and could do it a simpler way.

Comment: Ok I will try, any way Thank you David

Comment: Suggest breaking this out into two questions. One for InstallAware and one for InstallShield.  It's like your asking how to do something in C# and VB.Net.

Answer (score 3):

The user guide:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/DocumentRepository/Installation/InstallShield/InstallShield%202011%20Professional/01_Public/Product_Manual/InstallShield2011UserGuide.pdf

Has a section with examples from page 694 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

One must first know more about the DLL.  Is it a WinPE ( native ) dll with exported functions?  Is it a COM server?  Or perhaps it is a .NET assembly with or without ComVisible types.

A better answer can be provided if there is more information.

For InstallShield:

One way to consume a .NET ComVisible class is to write an InstallScript custom action and use the [DotNetCoCreateObject](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14langref/DotNetCoCreateObject.htm)() function.

Another approach would be to define a managed custom action.  Here is an [tutorial](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/03/installshield-2009-beta-part-ii-managed.html).

But my favorite approach is to write a DTF custom action to encapsulate your assembly.

Comment: It is a .Net assembly with ComVisible set to true

Comment: @Ghyath are you sure that your users will have the necessary version of .net at the time this install action will run?