# Call a method of a class of my dll with installshield

Tags: c#, dll, installshield-2010

> Maybe duplicate with
>
> [Call a dll function from InstallAware or InstallShield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656559/call-a-dll-function-from-installaware-or-installshield)

How can i call a method of a class of my dll at the end of the setup in installshield?

I have wrote something like the following code at the end of the Setup.Rul in my setup project and set the ComVisible of my dll and my class to true but i recieve this error yet :

> "DLL function call crashed: ISRT._ DotNetCoCreateObject"

```
...
 
szDLLCompletePath = SUPPORTDIR ^ "MyDllName.dll";
 
szClassName = "MyDllName.MyClassName";
 
//The error occured at the following line
set Obj = DotNetCoCreateObject( szDLLCompletePath, szClassName, "");
 
If(! IsObject(Obj)) then
    MessageBox("Cannot load", SEVERE);
 
else
    Obj.MyMethodName(Parameters);
endif;
```

Note: I have added my dll as support file to my setup project.

Please tell me if there is any sample for this.

Comment: Can you please show the code for your C# class. DotNetCoCreateObject creates an instance of your class. Do make sure it's not static. Also which line is it exactly crashing on?

Comment: @Abhi, Thanks for your reply. Yes your right, the problem is because of my code in my dll. because i have tried my setup with a simple dll and it works fine. But i need to do some complex works in my dll. I could not place my codes here however i could describe it for you: My code is for creating a user in a network.

Comment: Log to an external file in your c# code. Put Logging on every line. And execute from Installshield. Check where it fails.

Comment: I have loged in a registry key, and i found it has problem just at the beginning of method. I have a DLLImport and a struct in the class before my method.Do you think they could be the problem?

Comment: Comment out whatever you think is the problem and try.

Comment: I have tried your solution and i think the struct(which define the User_Info_1 to create new user in network) is the reason of problem.Note that i did'nt receive that mentioned error any more, but also the setup terminates before the welcome is shown.